# Infer generic class type parameters from single constructor parameter

Tags: java, generics, constructor

What I want is following:

Most of the time, the generic class will be like `TestBuilder<X, X>`, meaning that T and O are of the same type. Therefore I create two different constructor. I want to make anonoumous new calls like `new TestBuilder<>(...)` (I'm calling the `<>` anonoumous here).

Following 4 constructor example exists:

**1) Working constructor calls**

```
// Anonoumous, working
new TestBuilder<>(String.class, Integer.class)
    .withOnNext(new Action1<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer integer)
        {   
        }
});

// not anonoumous, classified, working
new TestBuilder<String, String>(String.class)
    .withOnNext(new Action1<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(String string)
        {
        }
});
```

**2) Constructor Calls with problems or not working**

```
// Anonoumous and working
// PROBLEM: withOnNext is called with Object instead of String
new TestBuilder<>(String.class)
    .withOnNext(new Action1<Object>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Object o)
        {
        }
});

// Anonoumous and NOT working
// this is what I want to work!
new TestBuilder<>(String.class)
    .withOnNext(new Action1<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(String string)
        {
        }
});
```

**Question**

Is there a way to get the 4th constructor to work? I don't want to be forced to give the constuctor two classes if I call it with one argument only, the second generic class should "inherit" from the first in this case... Instead of having to write `new TestBuilder<String, String>(String.class)` I want to write `new TestBuilder<>(String.class)` or at least `new TestBuilder<String>(String.class)`...

**Class**

*This is what the test builder class looks like:*

```
public class TestBuilder<T, O>
{
    public TestBuilder(Class<T> eventClass)
    {
        this(eventClass, (Class<O>)eventClass);
    }

    private TestBuilder(Class<T> eventClass, Class<O> observableClass)
    {
        init();
    }

    public TestBuilder<T, O> withOnNext(Action1<O> actionNext)
    {
        mActionNext = actionNext;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class<O> has to be determined/given or it will default to the `Object` type. A workaround is putting in generic types (constructor 2) or casting. Which is worse than input generic types. A possibility could also be using the private constructor. Though that would defeat the purpose of this whole mechanism.

Comment: are you actually using the ```Class<...>``` objects that you pass?

Comment: The first `Class<...>` object is used, the second one is for the generic class determination only...

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/MFlisar/RXBus/blob/test/lib/src/main/java/com/michaelflisar/rxbus/RXBusBuilder.java The first class is used as an object directly... To map objects in an HashMap to class types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Java can infer the second generic type without some kind of hint. One way is giving the type in variable declaration:

```
 TestBuilder<String, String> testBuilder = new TestBuilder<>(String.class);
 testBuilder.withOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
     @Override
     public void call(String string) {
         //...
     }
 });
```

But you'd still need to declare both generic parameters.

What I would do is encapsulating the information that both `T` and `O` are the same in a static factory method:

```
public  class TestBuilder<T, O> {
    public static <T> TestBuilder<T, T>  create(Class<T> eventClass) {
        return new TestBuilder<T, T>(eventClass);
    }
    // ...
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
TestBuilder.create(String.class).withOnNext(...);
```

---

Yet another option is encapsulating the information in a separate class inheriting from `TestBuilder`:

```
public class SimpleTestBuilder<T> extends TestBuilder<T,T> {
    public SimpleTestBuilder(Class<T> eventClass) {
        super(eventClass, eventClass);
    }
}

public class TestBuilder<T, O> {
    private TestBuilder(Class<T> eventClass, Class<O> observableClass) {
    }
    // ...
}
```

Used as

```
    new SimpleTestBuilder<>(String.class).withOnNext(...);
```

Yet another good option is to encapsulate the information `O` is same as `T` in a static method:

```
public  class TestBuilder<T, O> {
    public static <T> TestBuilder<T, T>  create(Class<T> eventClass) {
        return new TestBuilder<T, T>(eventClass);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Used as

```
TestBuilder.create(String.class).withOnNext(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. The static create function solution is a solution I like, did not think about it...

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a helper type variable for the first constructor like this:

```
public class TestBuilder <T, O>
{
    public <H extends T, O> TestBuilder(Class<H> c)
    {
        this((Class) c, (Class) c);
    }

    public TestBuilder(Class<T> c1, Class<O> c2)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestBuilder<String, String> hw = new TestBuilder<>(String.class);
        System.out.println(hw);
    }
}
```

This will create some `unchecked` warnings for the constructor, but not at the call site. Please note though that some might consider this ad practise, especially since not everyone knows about constructor type parameters. For the sake of completeness, the explicit invocation of the constructor has to look like this:

```
new<String> TestBuilder<>(String.class).doStuff()
```